# The maximal ideal of a local Dedekind domain is principal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

> Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension one that is also integrally closed (i.e. a local Dedekind domain), then $\mathfrak{m}$ is a principal ideal.

I am trying to follow the proof of Atiyah's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* in proposition 9.2. $ii)\Rightarrow iii)$.

The proof is as follows:

Let $a\in\mathfrak{m}$. There exists
$n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathfrak{m}^{n}\subseteq (a)$ but $\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}\nsubseteq(a) $. Choose $b\in\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}-(a)$. Then, if $x=a/b$, we have that $x^{-1}\notin A$ and therefore $x^{-1}$ is not integral over $A$. Now Atiyah says that $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\nsubseteq\mathfrak{m}$. Why is this true?

According to the book, if $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$, then $\mathfrak{m}$ would be a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module, finitely generated as an $A$-module.

I don't see why $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module, and I don't understand why this would be a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathfrak m$ is finitely generated as an ideal or as an $A$-module because $A$ is noetherian.

From Proposition 5.1(iv) we get that $x^{-1}$ is integral over $A$, a contradiction.